# Perpendicular Projection Linear Transformations

Tags: matrices, projection

If a linear transformation T has matrix A.

If T is a perpendicular projection onto the line y = -5x, then A has:

eigenvector [1, -5] (this is meant to be 2 rows, 1 column) with eigenvalue 1

how would I work out the second eigenvector and eigenvalue?

I thought that because it is a projection, the second eigenvalue would be 0, but does that mean the eigenvector is [0, 0]?

Comment: no; eigenvectors are (usually by definition, in this context at least) nonzero vectors. The eigenvalue being zero (which you're right about!) means that there's a nonzero vector $v$ such that $Av=0v=[0,0]$. do you have the matrix $A$? if so, can you solve that system of equations (up to scalar multiple)? if not, what nonzero vector(s) "should" get sent to the vector 0 under the transformation at hand, geometrically?

Comment: So should I use the eigenvector and eigenvalue I'm given to get A, using Av = λv, then use that to calculate the second eigenvalue and eigenvector?

Comment: ah, you don't have the matrix? yes, what you have should be enough to find $A$, since you can define the projection matrix $A$ in terms of the dot product with the eigenvector you have, and then see what each of its components are. (there is also a different, "intuitive" geometric way of seeing it, by the way...)

Comment: so, to be explicit, if we call the eigenvector you have now $v_1$, then by virtue of being a projection, for any vector $w$, $Aw=\frac{w\cdot v_1}{\lVert v_1 \rVert^2}v_1$. you can extract the columns of $A$ by evaluating on the basis vectors, $w=[1,0]$ and $w=[0,1]$. hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint.** You're correct about the first eigenvalue and eigenvector, as well as that the second eigenvalue is $0$. Now to find the eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda=0$, we must find a **nonzero** vector $v$ such that $Av=\lambda v$, in other words $Av=0$. Thus we just need to find a nonzero vector that is taken to $0$ under the linear transformation. In alternative language, we want to find a vector that spans the nullspace of $A$. Can you continue?

Comment: Should I use my first eigenvector and eigenvalue to get A, which gives me the 2x2 identity matrix? I am confused on how to solve for Av =0 as I am not sure what I can use for A.

Comment: @coolkid3127 Good question! There's no need to find $A$, and in fact it's not possible just from one eigenvector and eigenvalue. If you really wanted to find $A$, you could do that from the geometric description given: starting from a point $(x,y)$, what does the linear transformation map it to? But there's no need to do so for this question. Just consider what vectors would be mapped to the origin under the linear transformation? Think pictorially and geometrically.

Comment: in general that's true, but it is possible to extract $A$ from just one eigenvector here, given that we also know it's a projection and the space is 2-dimensional! the geometric intuition is also good to develop though.

Comment: My goal is to get the second eigenvector, I was going to try get A then go from there. Should I just go straight to the second eigenvector? If so I am still confused on how quite to get there. In this case what would the working be?

Comment: @coolkid3127 yes, it's sometimes a good idea to find the matrix $A$ and get the eigenvalue from there, but in this case there's a simpler way. Take out a piece of paper, draw out the line $y=-5x$ and some arbitrary point; draw what the linear transformation $T$, the perpendicular projection onto the line, does to this point. Once you understand it geometrically, ask yourself the question: which vectors in this whole 2D plane are mapped to the origin, $(0,0)$? Any such vector other than $(0,0)$ itself is an eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue $0$.

Comment: @thorimur Yes, of course, I agree with you, I meant that it couldn't be done in general. That's why I said $A$ can be found from the geometric description, but not purely from the eigenvector and eigenvalue.

Comment: So would the second eigenvector be [5, 1]?

Comment: @coolkid3127 Yes!